# DocuSign not finding anchor tab strings with Field codes in a word document

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to use [field codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/List-of-field-codes-in-Word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51) in our word documents to be our anchor tab strings. If I do a Ctrl-A on the document, I see the **field codes**, but it does not find them with Docusign. If I take those values, such as Seller_Nm, and place it on the document, away from the field codes, it finds it fine. Is there something else I need to do when using field codes?

Edit: here is the envelope definition and the summary

```
 05/15/2017 11:32:05 - INFO - Created Envelope with definition: {
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": "http://requestb.in/",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent"
      }
    ],
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "true",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false"
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "8ce7fea6-2ad1-4a45-a8c6-a29af4b2977d"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Lori",
                "email": "kathyxxx@gmail.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "accessCode": "12345",
                "customFields": [],
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "note": "",
                "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
                "emailNotification": {
                  "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
                  "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
                  "supportedLanguage": "en"
                }
              }
            ],
            "certifiedDeliveries": []
          },
          "customFields": {
            "textCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "EnvelopeInfo",
                "value": "my data"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "C:\\Temp\\Docusign\\TestTabPlacement.docx",
        "fileExtension": ".docx",
        "documentFields": [
          {
            "name": "DMSID",
            "value": "1"
          }
        ],
        "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Here is the subject"
}
```

And here is the summary:

```
 05/15/2017 11:32:12 - INFO - Envelope summary: {
  "envelopeId": "1e8408d2-c5e4-4c95-95bf-2055cdd9f8ad",
  "uri": "/envelopes/1e8408d2-c5e4-4c95-95bf-2055cdd9f8ad",
  "statusDateTime": "2017-05-15T15:32:12.6503852Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your JSON request and provide a link to the document you are using.

Comment: The link to the document is: https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents/details/1e8408d2-c5e4-4c95-95bf-2055cdd9f8ad

Comment: I am unable to access the document. Can you please post it to a publicly available URL.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NrQ61VNrt6SDNVc3lIeDktdmc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocuSign automatically converts word documents into PDFs when the document is uploaded. Looks like the field codes in the Word Document are no longer present in the PDF document. So DocuSign is unable to place Tags using the AnchorString.

***Troubleshooting Tip*** : Try saving your word document as PDF and see if your Anchor String is still present in the document.

Comment: I missed the part about Word "field codes". @CodingDawg is right, Word field codes are meta data that are not transferred to the pdf. Instead, put the anchors as plain text within the document, but with color white. That way they will not show in the pdf but they will be there and will work as anchor text.

Answer (score 0):

Your template may have "whole words" set for the anchor strings. Try separating the anchor strings from adjacent characters other than whitespace.

Comment: Yes, the anchor strings are whole words. But your second statement, I'm not sure I understand. Could you elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't make a difference. But it was a good idea.